# Standard method to insert any datetime format string to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am importing data from Excel file to SQL Server. My sheet contains some datetime columns. If it contains values in 'M/d/yyyy'(12/31/2015) format which is my systems datetime format it executes smoothly without any errors. But with values other than 'M/d/yyyy' format, it doesn't insert data and gives exception.

I am not even converting datetime values to specific format and then inserting, simply picking up the data inserting it to SQL Server. I am not able to understand what exactly the problem is and what it has to do with system datetime format.

The code I am using is:

```
select case when ISDATE(@SignalDateTime)=1 then @SignalDateTime else null end
```

The error I am getting is:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

If date is '12/21/2015' format its fine, but for any other format it gives error.

Comment: What is the exception? What is the code? What is your `CurrentCulture`? We need more details to solve your problem.

Comment: after posting this question .I searched for error statement where error occurs while insertind data.

Comment: after posting this question .I searched for error statement where error occurs while inserting data.Statement is:-select case when ISDATE(@SignalDateTime)=1 then @SignalDateTime  else null end.Error is:-'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value'.If date is '12/21/2015' format its fine.but for any other format it gives error.

Comment: @SignalDateTime is datetime type in stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

Use a parameterized query and set the parameter type to [`Datetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
      "INSERT INTO ... (..., datetimecolumn, ...) VALUES (..,@datetimeparameter,...", 
       connection);
SqlParameter datetimeParameter = new SqlParameter(
      "@datetimeparameter", 
       SqlDbType.Datetime);
datetimeParameter.Value = <your C# variable of type Date>;
...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Using a framework like Entity Framework would take care of a lot of the boilerplate coding.

Using [`SqlBulkCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) is another viable approach.

What does **not** work is passing in values as hard coded strings in T-SQL. Aside from SQL injection prone, slow and unperformant, there are countless issues around the combination of client (app) locale, server locale and SQL Server locale settings ([`SET DATEFORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)). For the record: there is a locale independent datetime format in SQL Server, namely the `YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss` format. Whenever you *must* use a T-SQL string to represent a date, use this format as is locale agnostic.

Also you might want to learn a bit about [SSIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) as it does what you're trying to achieve out-of-the-box (there is an [SSIS Excel source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141683.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

I did't test so i'm not 100% sure.
Can you change your column to be datetime2(7) on database? and then send the datetime in following format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.
I suggest that because the datetime2 as a Default string literal in above format while the datetime don't has it so it's based on the system culture.
 I suggest that because the Datetime2 has the default literal string while the DateTime don't have it you can Click [MSDN web site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) to find out more about it.

Answer (score -1):

Excel stores internally the datetime as a number. So you will probably have to read it as number as well and convert it "manually" before storing it in SQL